# Linux container (LNX) resource assignment

Tags: linux, linux-containers

For a linux container, after it is created and some application are running in it, can CPU and memory be dynamically added to the container?

Comment: What containers in your mind? Are you talking about java containers?

Comment: LNX (https://linuxcontainers.org/)

Comment: Thanks John, I didn't yet hear it. Let me check